Time handling with matDatePicker
I have component for handling date + time: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-b3wdcj]
When I change year/month/day manually in input (not in picker) , some events are fired (dateInput, ngModelChange). But when I change hours/minutes manually in matInput (just change 12 -> 13), nothing happens.
Is it possible to handle time change somehow?
I do not want to handle/set time in picker, but need to handle time change in matInput.
Thanks a lot for any advice.
T.

It seems like you're trying to capture changes in the time component of a date-time input using Angular Material. While the (ngModelChange) event fires when the date part is modified manually, it doesn't seem to react to changes in the time (hours/minutes) part of the input field.
            
To address this, you can indeed use the (input) event to capture changes in the input field, including changes in the time part. You've correctly added (input)="onModelChange2($event)" to your input element to listen for such changes.
            
Here's an example of how you can handle the validity component in stackblitz:
            <code>
         <input
            matInput
            name="dateTimeInput"
            [(ngModel)]="validityDate"
            required
            (input)="onModelChange2($event)"
            (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)"
            (change)="onChange($event)"
            (dateInput)="dateInput($event)"
            (dateChange)="dateChange($event)"
            (focusout)="onFocusout($event)"
            (hoursChanged)="onHoursChanged($event)"
            [matDatepicker]="datePicker"
          />
        </code>
    
In this example, onModelChange2(event: any) method is triggered whenever there is any change in the input field, including changes in the time part. Inside this method, you can extract the updated date-time value from the input field, convert it to a Date object, and perform any necessary actions based on the updated time.

